# Hibernate subquery - MAX

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a problem in creating subquery with Hibernate.
Suppose, we have a query like this (we want to select zoo containing the oldest tigers):

```
 SELECT * FROM zoo LEFT JOIN animals 
 ON animals.zoo_id = zoo.id
 WHERE animals.species = 'tigers' AND 
 animals.age = (SELECT max(age) FROM animals WHERE animals.species = 'tigers')
```

In Hibernate, it would look like this:

```
    session.createCriteria(Zoo.class) 
    .createAlias("animals", "a") 
    .add(eq("a.species", "tigers"))
    .add(eq("a.age", ?);
```

but unfortunately I don't know how to set subquery:

```
(SELECT max(age) FROM animals WHERE animals.species = 'tigers')
```

Comment: Why don't you use createQeury instead of Criteria?

Comment: @YusufK. this example is simplified. Query, which I modify, is more complex.

Comment: It is a bit complex but DetachedCriteria and .add(Subqueries......) may help.